# Mathematical problems that are too computationally complex, so we use probability distributions instead?

Tags: probability, computational-complexity, computability

Some mathematical truth statements/questions can not be answered with certainty. This could be because

1. The computation required to answer them is finite but requires a universe-sized computer to work on it for longer than the age of the universe.
2. The question has an answer, but the computation required to answer them is infinite, so that they can never be answered. (I'd like to know an example of this).
3. Godel's theorem??? (despite reading a lot on this, I still don't fully understand what it means).

**But my question is: Are there examples of problems that are not solvable in an exact way, but where we nevertheless have some exact algorithm that gives us a meaningful probability distribution over answers to the problem?**

For example, we could have a function $f:X \to \{\text{yes,no} \}$, and a function $g:X\to [0,1]$, where we know that $f$ is fully defined for every $x\in X$, but we cannot compute it (or it takes a long time to compute so that we can only compute it for say 100 values in a year with a super computer), and where if we calculate $g(x)$ for various $x$, it will on average make meaningful probability statements about what the value of $f(x)$ is. It could be that while $f$ is computationally intractable, $g$ is very efficient.

Is there an example vaguely like this? (it doesn't have to fit my exact formulation).

**To be clear, I'm not asking for "approximations" to $f$, but specifically for probability distributions over answers of $f$.**  I am also not asking for an approximate probability distribution *to another probability distribution*. I'm asking for a probability distribution over *mathematical truth statements* that while they may not be computable have an actual true answer.

---

**Edit:** The Prime Number Theorem is a very good example. I am also wondering if there are any good examples of theorems that are unproven, but where there is nevertheless some sort of probability estimate possible regarding whether it's true or not. (I've read something regarding the Goldbach conjecture [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9639.00108/full), but the argument seems obviously wrong).

Comment: For example, we don't know how to obtain a lot of the multivariate integrations which is a huge topic in approximation theory, along with computational science and engineering. However we do have a method to approximate this, typically, Monte carlo.

Comment: Please read my last sentence. I very specifically am not asking for an approximation.

Comment: Would the Prime Number Theorem be an example ?

Comment: How do you define the "exactness"? If the machine can only accurately compute upto certain level (e.g. 1e-20), would you say this is exact?

Comment: What is a "meaningful probability statement" about values of $f$?

Comment: @gandalf61, Yes! thank you! The prime number theorem seems to be exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I'd love to see more things like that. The only thing that makes me kind of hesitate, is that it says that the probability distribution is only "approximately true for large $N$". I'm wondering if there are examples where the probability distribution is exact. Nevertheless, this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.

Comment: @induction601, by exactness, I simply mean, that there is an exact answer. For example, the answer to the question "25*3=75" is simply "yes", and the answer to the question "25*3=?" is simply "75".

Comment: @Rahul, I don't know exactly what I mean by meaningful, but it means something like: "on average, the probability given by $g$ should correspond to the true answer". For example, if $g(x)=0.9$ for all $x$, while $f(x)=no$ for almost all $x$, then this is not a "meaningful" distribution. Perhaps I should have said "correct" instead.

Comment: The halting problem is quite literally an instance of 2. You need to run the program for an infinite time to be sure it never halts.

Comment: @Rohan, yes precisely. Thank you. Here it is: http://www.lbatalha.com/blog/feynman-on-fermats-last-theorem

Comment: @Rohan, yes ofcourse. Hopefully there are more examples of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very general answer to this is the "logical induction" algorithm described in [this paper](http://intelligence.org/files/LogicalInduction.pdf). Also, the introduction to this paper has some discussion of what a "meaningful" function $g$ might look like.

I should say ahead of time that, like many results in the vein of "this function is computable", the algorithm in question is not going to be remotely efficient: it will take a very long time (an impractical length of time) for it to make nontrivial probability estimates.

In any case, the idea is that the logical inductor will produce consistent probability estimates for *all* mathematical statements you give it; the more time you give the logical inductor to work, the more reasonable the probability estimates. (By contrast, there is no similar algorithm that produces truth values for all mathematical statements.) Essentially, the longer the logical inductor runs, the more facts it learns, and it uses those facts to guess at truth values it hasn't learned.

(It is easy to come up with an algorithmic prover that, inefficiently, finds more and more proofs of mathematical statements over time. Just iterate over all finite strings, and for each string, check if it's a proof of something. Such a prover feeds into the logical inductor, and gives it a basis for making its guesses. Of course, there are unprovable statements that the prover will *never* say anything about, and we still want the logical inductor to assign them probabilities.)

You should imagine the algorithm working as follows. Suppose that the statement we're interested in is "The $3^{\text{rd}}$ digit of $\pi$ after the decimal is $1$" encoded as a statement in Peano arithmetic or something. Over time, the logical inductor's beliefs might change as follows:

1. Initially, it will assign the statement a value around $0.5$, on the grounds that all statements are either true or false.
2. It takes a *relatively* short time (compared to the next stages) to realize that decimal digits are values in $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$, and this convinces the logical inductor to drop the estimate down to $0.1$.
3. After proving some estimates of $\pi$, such as $\pi \approx \frac{22}{7} = 3.1415...$, the logical inductor would have more refined estimates of the digits. For instance, maybe it would think that the digit is $1$ with probability $\frac13$ and $2$ with probability $\frac13$, since $3.141$ and $3.142$ are both close to $\frac{22}{7}$, with the remaining probability mass assigned to other digits.
4. Eventually, a proof is found that $3.141 \le \pi < 3.142$, and the statement has probability $1$.

(These are only intuitions, since of course I don't have a practical implementation to test this on; it might turn out that there are ways to bypass some of these stages.)

The same would happen (over a different scale of time) to something like the $1000000000^{\text{th}}$ digit of $\pi$, or to other statements we don't know the truth value of.

Answer (score 2):

I think an example is factoring, rephrased as a decision problem ("Does $n$ have a prime divisor between $a$ and $b$?").  By Rubinstein's theorem, this is decidable in worst-case $n^{\frac{1}{3}+o(1)}$ time.  On the other hand, if we use a deterministic version of GNFS and restrict the time to be subexponential, we can't prove it is correct, but if it runs out of time we can output some small probability.

A similar example is provided by the AKS prime test versus Miller-Rabin, however these are both polynomial so we can only quantify the difference with fine-grained time complexity (a specific model of computation).  But in the former example the advantage is invariant under polynomial time-translations of the model.

And trivially, for a finite search problem like the above, there is a time-probability trade-off.  Randomize the search space, or pseudo-randomize if that's good enough.  Now if we check $X\%$ of the space without finding anything then there's an $X\%$ chance that there's nothing there to be found.

As far as being able to take an arbitrary statement and put a probability on that without actually proving it, I'm not aware of any standard way of doing this, however I've explored a few different approaches myself independently.  One example is that we can extend arithmetic with a kind of quantifier interpreted as "it is probably true that if we pick a number $n$ then the following statement will hold of $n$".  Then we can prove such statements for certain uncomputable numbers derived from Chaitin's constant. 
 Here is [a brief explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252643/seeking-general-information-about-modal-probability-arithmetic) of this theory (my question seeking more information is still unanswered).  Another idea I've been interested in more recently is [assigning a probability measure to a set of consistent extensions of a theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574998/on-defining-a-probability-measure-on-theories-and-relevance-to-arithmetic), then understanding the "probability" of a statement as being the measure of the set of such extensions that can't refute it.  Misha Lavrov's excellent answer represents another general approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with a quote from Feynman: $$\text{ For my money Fermat’s Theorem is true. }$$

We should note that this comment was made in context to Feynman’s checking of the validity of FLT and he made a calculation that the probability FLT would be false was “certainly less than $10^{-200}$”. Silvan Schweber encountered among Feynman’s papers, a sketch of his unpublished *probabilistic* analysis of FLT. That is, he didn’t try to formally prove the conjecture but rather tried to show that it is statistically improbable that it is false.

Now, what did Feynman do with this idea of using probability to study Fermat’s Last Theorem?

---

He first asks: “What is the probability that $N$ is a perfect $n^{\text{th}}$ power?”. Feynman’s approach to answering this was to start by mapping the unit interval defined by two large consecutive integers ($N$ and $N+1$) into the shorter interval of the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of the unit interval, note the **mapping is monotonic**.

To determine the length of the shorter interval, Feynman wrote it as: $$l = (N+1)^{\frac1{n}}-N^{\frac1{n}} \approx \frac{N^{\frac1{n}}}{nN}\, \text{ (N large) } \, \tag 1$$

Feynman then said that the required prob. is given by $(1)$ and therefore the probability that $x^n + y^n$ is a perfect $n^{\text{th}}$ power is: $$P = \frac{(x^n + y^n)^{\frac1{n}}}{n(x^n + y^n)}\tag 2$$ and thus the total probability that $x^n + y^n$ is a perfect $n^{\text{th}}$ power [that is $z^n$] for any $x > x_0$ and $y > y_0$ is equal to: $$\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} (x^n + y^n)^{-1+\frac1{n}} \, dx \, dy = \frac{2}{nx_0^{n-3}}c_n$$ $$\text{ where } c_n = \frac12 \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} (u^n + v^n)^{-1+\frac1{n}}\, du\, dv$$

---

I can write more but I have given the gist of Feynman’s brilliance. For further references:

$[1]$ Number-Crunching: Taming Unruly Computational Problems from Mathematical Physics to Science Fiction, Paul J.Nahin (pp. 1-13) A full account is given here, out of which I have given an excerpt.

$[2]$ As shared by the OP in request to my comment, the same is given [here](http://www.lbatalha.com/blog/feynman-on-fermats-last-theorem) as well.

Comment: could you maybe say something about the fact that Feynman's conclusion is obviously wrong? to say that there was a $10^{-20}$ probability that the conjecture is false, is surely complete nonsense (before it was proved that is). This would mean that every time we did a probability calculation like that, we would only be wrong once in ever $10^{20}$ times we did such a probability estimate. There must certainly be something completely wrong in his argument.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Well, as I have written in my first paragraph, Feynman set out **not to prove FLT**, but tried to **show it is statistically improbable** it *would be false*. How did he do that? Via these calculations! Even see the last paragraph in your link, where they have given an estimate.

Comment: I don't think you understood my point. I know he didn't try to prove it. I am saying that his estimate is WAY too small, and that therefore there must be something wrong in his argument. Clearly no sane person would assign a $10^{-20}$ probability to a conjecture being false. Feynman must have made an implicit assumption that is incorrect.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Most mathematicians have a penchant for understatement. Feynman is probably one of the few mathematicians that didn't shy away from a hyperbole.

Comment: @Robert, perhaps, but the interesting thing here is: what is it thats wrong with feynmans argument. Where is he making a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Programmer2134 when somebody makes a joke, do we go around nitpicking about the joke's truth-value? But in any event, we only need to know FLT for prime numbers. If you consider any distribution on the prime numbers and use current knowledge about the ranges where the FLT is true, you can calculate a probability that the FLT is true. These distributions would most likely place too much "weight" on early primes, and thus you could contest the veracity of the statement that anyone cooks up. But anyone making such a claim is just doing it recreationally.

Comment: The point is that in a "random model" of perfect powers, FLT is almost certainly true. This is a calculation worth doing. It means that if FLT were false, there would almost certainly have to be some underlying behavior forcing perfect powers and their sums together. (What is likelier: that a $1$ in $10^{200}$ coincidence happens, or that some deep fact in number theory is responsible?) But of course the presence of this underlying behavior is a priori far likelier than $10^{-200}$. Other conjectures in number theory, such as the Riemann hypothesis, have a similar true-if-random flavor.